# how to store custom arraylist into sqlite and retrieve it

Tags: android, arraylist, android-sqlite

i need to store my custom arraylist int sqlite db and retrieve it .

the arrylist am using is

```
List<LessonContent> list = new ArrayList<LessonContent>();
```

lessonContent is an object with

```
 public LessonContent(String n, String a, String c) {
        node = n;
        attribute = a;
        content = c;

    }
```

and i store it in list as this way..

```
LessonContent textobj = new LessonContent(tagname,type,content);
                                 list.add(textobj);
```

and i have stored it in sqlite this way.. because i read some other questions that we cannot able to store the arraylist directly to sqlite so convert it into json string.

```
// saving list to sqlite db
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

json.put("uniqueArrays", new JSONArray(list));
String arrayList = json.toString();

    Lessons lns =new Lessons(lesson_id,subject,chapter,arrayList);
    db.addContent(lns);
```

towards this codes there is no issues...

now i need to read the stored datas from sqlite..

for that i use this piece of code..

```
Lessons lsn = db.getContent(lesson_id);
String xmlcontent = lsn.getLesson();
      JSONObject json = null;

json = new JSONObject(xmlcontent);

list = (List<LessonContent>) json.optJSONArray("uniqueArrays");
```

i got error this stage as cannot cast a json object to list..

please any one know the correct way to store my arraylist in db and read it back..

Comment: you can not cast a JSONArray to a List<LessonContent>. You have to parse your json array and build the List

Comment: is there any other methods to store and retrieve my arraylist